# Is there a difference between saying この時計は 高いです。 and 高い時計です。

Tags: grammar, meaning

Hello as the title says I want to know if there is a difference between these two sentences :

1. この時計は 高いです。
2. 高い時計です。

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's about as much difference here as there would be between the phrases "This watch is expensive" and "This is an expensive watch". They're interchangeable for the most part, but keep in mind the subtle difference.

So say for example, you wanted to say something like, "According to this expensive watch, it's 3 o'clock". It's more natural to phrase it like,

> 「この高い時計によれば、３時です」 (According to this expensive watch, it's 3 o'clock)

rather than to split things up and say it like,

> 「この時計は高いですが、この時計によれば、３時です」 (This watch is expensive, and according to this watch, it's 3 o'clock).

Native speakers tend to go for the sentences that convey their thoughts the best with the least amount of effort. That goes for any language though. Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: 「高いこの時計**によって**X時です」 is incorrect, I'm afraid... You'd say 「この時計**では・によれば・によると**X時です」